# Delphi for PHP - location of source

Tags: php, delphi4php

I just installed Delphi for PHP to get an idea on how it works and have created a simple app with a button that puts a text into a listbox when it is clicked.
The app works if I copy all required files to my webserver and run it from there.
It also works if I save the project in the standard path:
"c:\documents and settings\username\My Documents\Delphi for PHP Projects"

But if I save the project in another directory, the ButtonClick event is not fired when the application runs from there. I've put a breakpoint in the event to see if it stops there but it doesn't.

The OnShow event of the form works as usual.

It really seems to be the path where the project is located to make it either work or not.
As I said, I have no experience with Delphi for PHP so far, it is probably just a simple solution that I don't see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source should be at same driver of your Delphi 4 PHP installation, it is protection against cross site scripting.

So, if you install D4PHP under C:, your code should be under C: as well.

It is not a Delphi 4 PHP limitation, it is how the things works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy your project with Deployment Wizart ;)